# getParameterMetaData() throws java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "F": invalid identifier

Tags: java, oracle12c, ojdbc, ora-00904

I have written a simple program in java, which creates connection to Oracle database and executes update query.

The query gets executed successfully, but if the update query contains a column starting with "F" then `prepareStatement.getParameterMetaData()` throws exception

> "java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "F": invalid identifier".

If I remove the column starting with "F" then  `prepareStatement.getParameterMetaData()` executes correctly.

**My configruation is,**

`Oracle: 12.1.0.2`

`JDK: 1.8`

`ojdbc driver: ojdbc7.jar (included in 12.1.0.2)`

I found the same issue with `ojdbc6.jar` as well.

Is there any issue with the driver?

**Code:**

public class TestDriver {

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String sql = "UPDATE test SET test1 = ?, Fun=? WHERE test2 = ?";
    PreparedStatement ppt = null;
    Connection connection = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521/pdborcl2","oracleTrunk","oracleTrunk");
     ppt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

    for(int i=0; i<1;i++) {
    ppt.setString(1, null);
    ppt.setString(2, null);
    ppt.setString(3, "1");
    ppt.executeUpdate();
    System.out.println("MSG "+ppt.getParameterMetaData());
    }
    }catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("e  "+e);
    } finally {
        try {
            ppt.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This really sounds like a bug to me, since the `PreparedStatement` works as expected. However, I found a **workaround**:

If you use quotes to define your columns, the `ppt.getParameterMetaData()` does not throw an exception any more.

So you need to write

```
String sql = "UPDATE test SET test1 = ?, \"FUN\"=? WHERE test2 = ?";
```

Keep in mind that when using double quotes to define names in Oracle you have to be case sensitive. Thus it is `\"FUN\"` and not `\"Fun\"` because all names are converted to uppercase when used without quotes.

Comment: BTW: my test setup was: `Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production`, `JDBC 12.1.0.1.0` and `Oracle JDK build 1.8.0_66-b17`